# how to use alias from select query

Tags: php, mysql, variables, time, alias

i have a question how to use an alias from a select query:

```
$timecheck = $db->query("SELECT DOE <= NOW() AS trigger FROM table WHERE a='$a'");
                if ($trigger != 0){
                    do  something
            }
```

is this the right way to use an alias? i need the alias trigger to check for a validation of a timestamp period. if that period is 0 or less means 'trigger' will output 1. in case of that another query should be performed.

so i hope my question is clear enough. i would really appreciate if there is someone who could help. thanks alot.

Comment: Just an incidental remark: You need to put `trigger` in back quotes because it is a reserved word. `\`trigger\``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "trigger" may be a reserved word. Try:

```
$timecheck = $db->query("SELECT (DOE <= NOW()) AS trggr FROM table WHERE a='$a' ");
$trggr = //getting the value
if ($trggr != 0){
    // something
}
```

Comment: this doesnt work. i get the errormessage that there will be an unexpected T_IF for the line with $trggr = //getting the value

Comment: Yes, you should replace the //getting the value with the actual code, which fills $trggr. In fact I am not complete sure if it will be filled automatic, as you postet in your code.

Comment: you mean i have to repeat $timecheck just on another variable name $trggr and leave the alias... :)

Answer (score 1):

`trigger` is a reserved keyword, so you need to encapsulate it in back ticks. This will work:

```
SELECT DOE <= NOW() AS `trigger` FROM table WHERE a='$a'"
```

Answer (score 0):

An [IF()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) call should do the trick:

```
SELECT IF( DOE <= NOW(), 1, 0 ) AS `trigger` FROM ...
```

**Edit:** added backticks to trigger as noted by Kristian.

Answer (score -1):

i believe it should be something like this...

```
$timecheck = $db->query("SELECT DOE <= NOW() AS trigger FROM table WHERE a='$a'");
while ($timecheck->fetchInto($row, DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC)) {
    if ($row['trigger'] != 0){
      do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Its general.
And some times we can use like this also. Its depend on the server. (without using "AS")

"SELECT DOE <= NOW() trigger FROM table WHERE a='$a'"